# How to generate cucumber-rails for a different folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I'm trying to create a test folder for my rails project using cucumber-rails generator (the gem is here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails ).

The problem is that when I run "rails generate cucumber:install" it creates a folder in my project named "features" with the cucumber files inside that folder, which is - in my perspective - not very organized.

I would like all the cucumber files to be inside a folder named "test". Is there a way that allows me to do that? I tried to run the generator inside the "test" folder but it didn't seem to work.

Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are essentially 3 test libraries in Ruby and corresponding common assumptions:

- `test` is expected to contain `Test::Unit` or `MiniTest` tests
- `spec` is expected to contain `RSpec` tests
- `features` is expected to contain `cucumber` tests

You should follow these assumptions or you may end up having several troubles in the long run.

In any case, to answer your question, what you want to do is not possible. The `features` folder is [hard-code in the generator](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/v1.4.2/lib/generators/cucumber/install/install_generator.rb#L22-L23) and in the [cucumber task file](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/v1.4.2/lib/generators/cucumber/install/templates/tasks/cucumber.rake.erb#L35-L36). Therefore, unless you want to introduce several hacks and workaround, you'll have to follow the conventions.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know about that convention.
Well, then I'll follow it, I just thought it's not the best organization of all times (and I was checking the code of the generator and noticed that it was hardcoded).
Anyways, thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a pretty straight forward solution for this:

In an [issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/518) it is pointed out that we can point to different paths for our features in the cucumber.yml

```yaml
default: features 
// becomes 
default: test/features
```

But, then it can't find the `step_defintions` if you also add your custom path as a required flag then it can pick up the step_defintions as well.

```yaml
default: features 
// becomes 
default: test/features -r test/features/step_definitions
```

if you don't want to use `cucumber.yml` you can use the cucumber cli to take care of it:

```
bundle exec cucumber test/features -r test/features/step_definitions
```

NOTE: I am using this in a docker environment and this works fine for both local and docker implementations.